# Getting an array with the content of attributes

Tags: c#

I have a class in my code in C# where I want to get all the attributes from a nested class in an array with the size of the number of parameters and the content of all of them in an array of objects. Like these:

```
class MyClass {
 class Parameters {
  public const string A = "A";
  public const string B = "B";
  public const string C = "C";
  public const string D = "D";
  public const string E = "E";
  public const string F = "F";
 }    

 public object[] getAllParameters() {
    object[] array = new object[6];
    array[0] = Parameters.A;
    array[1] = Parameters.B;
    array[2] = Parameters.C;
    array[3] = Parameters.D;
    array[4] = Parameters.E;
    array[5] = Parameters.F;
}       
//more methods and code
```

}

But if I want to add for example, `G` and `H` parameters, I would have to update the size of the method `getAllParameters`, the initialization and more stuff in other parts of the code.

Could I do this "`getAllParameters`" method more generic, without taking account of the explicit parameters? With reflection maybe?

Comment: Where is the "subclass"? Do you just mean the nested class? Why does that nested class have them as separate fields? It seems odd to me...

Comment: You're right. I meant nested. I have just edited it. They are separated from MyClass in the nested class Parameters to have them in a block, not interfering with the MyClass fields. Why does it seem odd? Thanks!

Comment: It's odd to have all these separate fields - why doesn't the class just have a method you can call to get the parameters?

Comment: It might have this method to get the parameters. I could move the getAllParameters inside the Parameters class, but anyway I would like a way to not have to count the parameters with an explicit integer when creating the array. Maybe my solution is not very clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the fields are constants, you don't need an object instance just use `null` in `GetValue`. Also - these are fields, not properties.

```
  var fields = typeof(Parameters).GetFields();
  object[] array = new object[fields.Count()];
  for (int i = 0; i < fields.Count(); i++)
  {
    array[i] = fields[i].GetValue(null);
  }
  return array;
```

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try this.

Comment: @pablof how did you get on?

Comment: Just one thing more. Is it guaranteed that the array will send the fields in the order that they are declared?

Comment: @pablof I think so - just test it? It mmay do them alphabetically but either way you can use `IEnumerable.OrderBy` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to serialize the class to an array, so why reinvent the wheel? Use existing methods of serializing objects and customize them to your particular need.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a strange way to do it, but it is possible. You need both the instance of the object and the type of it, you can then get all the properties on the type, loop through each of them and get the value of each said property in the instance of said class.

```
TestClass obj = new TestClass();
Type t = typeof(TestClass);
foreach (var property in t.GetProperties())
{
    var value = property.GetValue(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using reflection.

```
typeof(MyClass).GetFields ();
```

will return a FieldInfo array. you van then get the value of each field by using

```
filedinfo.GetValue (myobject);
```

Comment: You don't need `myobject`, you can just use `null` :)

Comment: Exactly! You could instansiate the `Properties` class (which would be `myobject` and this would work, but there isn't a need for instansiation :)

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection. Here is an example:

```
class A
{
    public string F1;
    public string F2;
}
```

And in the method:

```
var a = new A();
var fields = typeof (A).GetFields();

var values = from fieldInfo in fields
             select fieldInfo.GetValue(a);
```

Comment: OP has fields, not properties.

Answer (score -1):

You can combine [Type.GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) with [PropertyInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue.aspx)

Comment: OP has fields, not properties.

Comment: So he can use Type.GetFields